# Edit a link with javascript prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have an html link like this:

```
<li id="schedule">
    <a href="/schedule?sku=102333">text </a>
</li>
```

I would like to change the link (href attribute) that this anchor tag points to using javascript.

In my case, I would like to replace the value of the `sku` in the query string (ie replace '102333' with another number).

Comment: You can try this :

    mylink = document.getElementById("schedule").firstElementChild;
    mylink.href="xyz.php";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this: http://jsfiddle.net/mig1098/ex6efsce/

```
var d = document.getElementById('schedule');

var chil = d.children[0];
var data = prompt('your data');

chil.setAttribute('href','/schedule?sku='+data);
alert(chil);

var url = chil.getAttribute('href');
var m = url.replace(/\/schedule\?sku\=/,'');
var r = document.getElementById('resp');
r.value = m;
```